# CSS doesnt work on wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to make the fonts of the "search here" bigger in a search plugin and i am failing.I am using the same plugin in two websites,in one it works fine and in the second it doesnt.The code i am using is

```
#ajaxsearchlite1 .probox .proinput input, div[id*="ajaxsearchlite"] .probox .proinput input {
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Open Sans;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
font-size: 16px !important;
line-height: normal !important;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border: 0;
box-shadow: none;
height: 34px;
```

}
 the website is www.superfruits.gr 
can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `font-family: 'Open Sans'`

Comment: I am sorry i meant make the fonts bigger,like 16px

Comment: Can you use developer tools and inspect what's happening? It's possible you're not targeting the correct class...

Comment: I think i am doing it right since i am using the same css on another website with the same plugin and it works fine

Comment: I think you'll have to include the link to your site in the question, as it is very specific, and difficult to help without it.

Comment: alright just did

Comment: It's the search box in the middle? With font-size of 2.6em !important?

Comment: yes exactly i want it to be 16px and its 12 px

Comment: Is that link for the site that is working then? Because the font-size is 2.6em, not 12px

Comment: yea check again it was some left over css from before that 2.6 em.Now i have it on my custom css as 16px but it shows as 12px,and thats my problem basically

Comment: It's showing 16px !important for me. Press ctrl + F5 to refresh your browser.

Comment: you are right on chrome even though i refresh it still shows 12px but on firefox it shows 16px.Must be cache right?Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes, cache issue. No problem

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove div[id*="ajaxsearchlite"] ?

Comment: I have tried it,I have located even the css files of the plugin in my cpanel changed them but still nothing,

Comment: Okay, if you edit anything in your css for example a text size does it change?

Comment: Okay, have you tried to inspect the code from your web browser?

Comment: yes ofcourse,it works fine when you do it from the incpector.it just doesnt apply on the custom css